# Developing shiny app as a package, How to document the function?

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I am a beginner in *shiny* and I am trying to make the package of my shiny application and then I will put it on the docker for future purpose use.
For doing so, I made the launch_application function

```
#' @export
runExample <- function() {
appDir <- system.file("shiny-examples", "myapp", package = "mypackage")
if (appDir == "") {
stop("Could not find example directory. Try re-installing `mypackage`.", 
call. = FALSE)
}

  shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
}
```

I am not able to document this function. :( Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to document"? What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: Thanks for replying....
When I hit the command to launch the app
mypackage::runExample()

I am getting the error saying
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘mypackage’

I guess I am missing something after creating the function.

Comment: Did you install the package you created?

Comment: No...I didn't.
Is it the same way to install.package("") ?
But this is created in my local directory.

How to do that?

Comment: I think it is best if you read some documentation on writing R packages. See for example this book http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: You need to document the package (`devools:: document ()`) prior to installing, so the `@export` takes effect.

Comment: Now My package is running successfully and no problem with at all but I am wondering why this package is not in a .zip file like every other package in R? It should be in .zip file so I can able to share with my sub-coordinate and they will install the package on their PCs.